# NVD3 width error inside Tabs

Tags: d3.js, tabs, zurb-foundation, nvd3.js

I am very new to charting with D3 and NDV3.

I am putting the charts inside tabs.  (Using Foundation 6.4)

The first chart is fine but the chart on the next clicked tab has a width issue.  If I re-size the window it expands to the proper size.

Here is the code based on their example.  Both charts are the same code - just with different IDs.

Thanks for any insight on using charts inside jquery tabs.

the code:

```
          <div id="chart1"></div>

          <script>

            var chart;
            var data;
            var legendPosition = "top";

            nv.addGraph(function () {
              chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                .options({
                  duration: 300,
                  useInteractiveGuideline: true
                })
              ;

              chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel("Time (s)")
                .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'))
                .staggerLabels(true)
              ;

              chart.yAxis
                .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
                .tickFormat(function (d) {
                  return d3.format(',.2f')(d);
                })
              ;

              data = sinAndCos();

              d3.select('#chart1').append('svg')
                .datum(data)
                .attr('height', 400)
                .call(chart);

              nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

              return chart;

            });

            function sinAndCos() { ... }

          </script>
```

First tab is fine - second one is very narrow.

[image]

[image]

this is the link for the Foundation Tabs.

https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html

Thank you very much. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code of nvd3 the width and height are determined by the `style` attribute of the svg.

Add the `svg` to the `div` yourself and give it a `style` attribute. Maybe it also works with a CSS style width and height, for responsive websites. Just like an image you specify the size.

```
<div id="chart1">
    <svg id="svg-chart1" style="width:800;height:400;"></svg>
</div>
<script>
  ....
  d3.select('#svg-chart1')
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);
  ....
</script>
```

Or with a different selector

```
<div id="chart1">
    <svg style="width:800;height:400;"></svg>
</div>
<script>
  ....
  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(data)
    .call(chart);
  ....
</script>
```

I used the line chart example from the NVD3 site and got errors on these lines

```
            .useInteractiveGuideline(true)  //We want nice looking tooltips and a guideline!
            .transitionDuration(350)  //how fast do you want the lines to transition?
```

so I commented them out. But looking at your example you set these with the `options()` method. Using `options()` I get the interactive guideline and no errors.

Comment: it looks like when I set the width:800 I end up loosing the responsive function.  so on smaller screens the chart gets covered up?

Comment: I was using this example from Git.  I think the errors you got were from the 3.5.17 update?  I noticed a few things different.

Comment: this seems to be the only example on the whole site that works inside a tab window. https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/lineChartSVGResize.html

Comment: Maybe set the width and height using CSS and media queries.

Comment: thanks.  I gave up on NVD3.  went back to Zingchart.